# chrome extension, execute every x minutes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm just making a simple chrome extension.

I want my background page(or part of ) to execute every 5 minutes, to get some data and  display a desktop notification if any.How can I do this

Comment: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/timers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be:

```
setInterval(your_function, 5 * 60 * 1000)
```

Which would execute `your_function` every 5 minutes (5 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds = 5 minutes)

Comment: How did nobody in 5 years point out that setInterval takes milliseconds, not seconds?

Comment: My assumption would be that the person looking at the above would be a developer. I can only speak for C#, Delphi and JavaScript, but their delays / timers always make use of milliseconds

Comment: What common languages utilize seconds? @GawieGreef

Comment: Sorry but I was being serious/curious if you didn't realise, I've only or atleast, mostly, worked with ms as far as I can remember. I think a thing or two in Java takes seconds from memory? EDIT: CSS is mostly used with decimal seconds (even though I think there are more units of time available in CSS) which sorta backs up your point about them being a developer, but more of a front-end web developer :p

Answer (score 31):

Important note: if you use a non-persistent background script (ManifestV3 `service_worker` or ManifestV2 [Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) with `"persistent": false` in manifest.json), `setInterval` with a 5-minute interval will likely fail as the background script will get unloaded after the idle timeout (30 seconds) unless you were lucky to have your other `chrome` event listeners fire in-between or you intentionally kept the background script alive ([MV3](/a/66618269), [MV2](/q/37017209)).

> If your extension uses window.setTimeout() or window.setInterval(), switch to using the alarms API instead. DOM-based timers won't be honored if the event page shuts down.

In this case, you need to implement it using the [`chrome.alarms`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) API:

```
chrome.alarms.create("5min", {
  delayInMinutes: 5,
  periodInMinutes: 5
});

// To ensure a non-persistent script wakes up, call this code at its start synchronously
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
  if (alarm.name === "5min") {
    doStuff();
  }
});
```

In case of persistent background pages, `setInterval` is still an acceptable [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8490416/934239). It should also work for short (on a scale of seconds, not minutes) intervals in a non-persistent script if you ensure the end is within the remainder of the idle timeout, see the above note.

Comment: When I create the alarm at `chrome.runtime.onStartup` in the background script, it still turns inactive and never awakens again.. Any idea?

Comment: If anyone has the same question/trouble as I had (see my comment from 3 November 2020): it does not work if you try to add an alarm listener within another listener (for example, onInstalled).