# Chrome Extension - event page inactive after less than 20 seconds

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a feed reader that checks for an updated version of the feed every hour or so.

My problem is that the event page seems to turn inactive after less than 20 seconds.

How do I make it last longer?

Here's some of the important parts of the code:

in manifest.json:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
```

and in eventPage.js:

```
function testFunc () {
    alert("test")
}
setInterval(testFunc, 10 * 1000) // was testing the number of seconds here
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Regards,

John

Comment: Why do you want to use setInterval? To "revive" the page after an hour?

Comment: I searched around and used the same method as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490385/chrome-extension-execute-every-x-minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `setInterval` to periodically run some code works fine on [background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html), but not on [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html), because the event page goes inactive when the page is idle for a long while.

The correct way to schedule a periodic task on event pages is to use the [`chrome.alarms`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html) API:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    if (alarm.name == 'name-of-alarm') {
        // Do something...
        testFunc();
    }
});

// Create the alarm:
chrome.alarms.create('name-of-alarm', {
    periodInMinutes: 60
});
```

Comment: Welp, I guess I was following the wrong method! Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: PS: I tried this code, but the alarm does not seem to be firing. I've added "alarms" to the permissions, but still not firing.

Comment: @user1239714 the background still gets inactive, how did you manage it to run? I've added the "alarms" to mainfest.json and set Rob's answer to the event page js eventPage.js

Comment: @YaBasha The event page is only reactivated if needed. In this question, the OP wanted to periodically trigger some action, for which the [`chrome.alarms`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html) API has to be used. If you don't want your page to go inactive at all, remove `"persistent": false` from your manifest file. It's recommended to use event pages when possible though, because that saves memory.

Comment: So should I put chrome.alarms in popup.js? I want to keep the persistent as it is false

Comment: Please ask a new question and provide the relevant context. @YaBasha