# Repeating a script using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension to fetch tweets and I figured that I could use the setInterval() function to make the script run every minute. First I tried giving it the function like this:

```
setInterval(myFunction(), interval);
```

But it would only execute my script once.
Then out of curiosity I tried declaring the function in the setInterval() function like so:

```
setInterval(function() {body of my function}, interval);
```

And that works, but is not a very pretty solution, does anybody any other way of doing this or am I just going to have to deal with it?

Comment: If you're using an event page, [use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15484602/938089) the [`chrome.alarms` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html) instead of `setInterval`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the brackets from the first call.  The reason for this is that you need to pass in the `function`, not the `result` of the function (what it returns).

When you write the `function`'s name with brackets, it calls the function.  When you exclude the brackets, it simply refers to the function like a variable, and so you can pass in your `function` to the `setInterval()` function.

```
setInterval(myFunction, interval);
```